# Connecting to websocket using SocketChannel Android

Tags: java, android, websocket, socketchannel, autobahn

I have written android app which connects to a websocket server, server app and android app implemented with **Autobahn** websocket library.

I can connect and exchange the messages with server successfully. but after some time(after 20 - 30 mins)  android app stop communicating with server(it cannot send messages to server). On logcat shows app still connect to websocket even though it cannot send messages to server.

I have went through the source code of Autobahn library and found that it using **java.nio.channels.SocketChannel** to connect to the websocket. Are there any issue in using SocketChannels? (I found similar issue from here [Android - How to keep connection with server for a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859744/android-how-to-keep-connection-with-server-for-a-long-time))

Comment: How does it fail? You send the message and the message is not available on the other side? What type of SocketChannel are you using (blocking/nonblocking)?

Comment: After sometime I cannot send messages to server from mobile. yes, the messages not available in other side. Autobahn library using blocking mode. This is the source code of the autobahn library - (https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketConnection.java)

Comment: It may be that the receiver is not processing the data fast enough. Take a look here, it might help: http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/05/30/tricks-and-tips-with-nio-part-i-why-you-must-handle-op_write/

Comment: I have solved the problem. Below is my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have solved the problem by using webscoket **ping/pong** message.

Actually the problem is not with the **SocketChannel**, I have tried with plain **Socket** instead of using SocketChannel. Problem not solved even with the **Socket**.

This is the approach that I have used...

In order to keep websocket connection alive we need to use Ping/Pong messages that built in support from websockt protocol(more information [websocket protocol](http://appwebserver.org/products/appweb/doc-4.3/guide/appweb/users/webSockets.html) ). Server need to send **ping** message in periodic time to clients. When ping receives from server, client replies it with **pong** message. Using this way we can keep the connection alive for ling time.

The Autobahn library that I have used to build my webscoket client support to this ping/pong messages. When ping message receives via websocket, library automatically send pong message to server. So we no need to worry about manually sending pong messages. You can find the autobahn implementation of ping/pong message from here (in **createHandler()** method - [autobahn ping/pong implementation](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/blob/master/Autobahn/src/de/tavendo/autobahn/WebSocketConnection.java))

You can get more details about this topic from this thread as well [Websockets. Loss of internet, keep-alive messages, app architecture etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758667/websockets-loss-of-internet-keep-alive-messages-app-architecture-etc)